# Nginx Add Secure Flag to Cookies from proxied server

Tags: configuration, nginx

Mozilla just released a new tool to check your website configuration.
observatory.mozilla.org

But the scan is complaining about 
Cookies (-10 points): Session cookie set without the Secure flag ...

Unfortunately the service running behind my nginx can only set the secure header if the SSL terminates there directly and not when SSL terminates on the nginx. Thus the "Secure" flag is not set on the cookies.

Is it possible to append the "secure" flag to the cookies somehow using nginx? Modifing the location/path seems to be possible.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know two ways to sorta do this, neither of them great.  The first is to just abuse proxy_cookie_path like this:

```
proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure";
```

The second is to use the more_set_headers directive from the **Headers More**  module like this:

```
more_set_headers 'Set-Cookie: $sent_http_set_cookie; secure';
```

Both of these can introduce problems because they blindly add the items.  For example if the upstream sets the *secure* flag you will wind up sending the client a duplicate like this:

```
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; secure; secure;
```

and in the second case if the upstream app does not set a cookie nginx will send this to the browser:

```
Set-Cookie; secure;
```

This is doubleplusungood, of course.

I think this problem needs to be fixed as many people has asked about it.  In my opinion a directive is needed something like this:

```
proxy_cookie_set_flags * HttpOnly;
proxy_cookie_set_flags authentication secure HttpOnly;
```

but alas, this does not currently exist  :(

Comment: The cookie path really looks like a nice workaround. I think I will try that first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I raised a [feature request](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,283436) in the forum; hopefully the author is interested in that.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [nginx_cookie_flag_module](https://github.com/AirisX/nginx_cookie_flag_module). It will solve your issue.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the module.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the module is setup and configured. The README seems to suggest that it requires rebuilding nginx, which might not be acceptable in many setups.

Comment: Yes, the useage of this module requires rebuilding Nginx. Otherwise you couldn't use it's directive. This applies to all third-party modules. In many cases, nginx rebuilding does not take much time.

Comment: @ThomasNyman Rebuilding can be avoided by paying for NGINX Plus, as explained in [instruction from NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/modules/cookie-flag/).

Comment: @Airis So you are the author? Great job, mate, but better to add a disclaimer.

Comment: @Aris we tried to use the module with 1.17.1 version of ngnix:alpine , but we face following errors once we try to load the modules to nginx.conf .  'module "/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_cookie_flag_filter_module.so" is not binary compatible'

Comment: I found the following gist useful in building this module: https://gist.github.com/muuvmuuv/f1a0e7b6a6a02c2253dc92350eab7607